# howto copy folder "test" to another folder with icreased number test1, test2 test3

Tags: directory, copy

I am very new to this but making progress every day.

I am a bit stuk now...

What I want to do is the following:

Copy folder /test to another folder called /test

But what I would like to do to is when every time I execute the "copy" command, I would like it to check if the /test folder already exists, if so increase a number in de folder name, like /test1, /test2 etc etc.. and start over if for example test10 is reached.

What is the best method to do this?

Comment: Maybe logrotate?

Comment: Simply make a bash / python script.

Comment: @Jean-Marie Either that or use a proper versioning tool like git. Sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me.

Comment: logrotate does not do what is asked, as it would copy test(x) to test(x+1), while Björn asks for more and more copies of test. However I suspect that this is really meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a folder named test, write a shell script `copytest` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
while true
do
    if [ -d test$i ]
    then
        i=$((i+1))
    else
        cp -r test test$i
        break
    fi
    if [ $i -eq 11 ]
    then
        rm -r test{1..10}
        cp -r test test1
        break
    fi
done
```

Now make it executable with `chmod u+x copytest` and each time you call `./copytest` you'll get a new copy named `test<n>`.

Explanation:

- `[ -d test$i ]` checks whether there is already a folder test$i
- `break` exits the otherwise infinite loop initiated by `while true`.
- The eleventh call will delete all copies and begin again with test1.

This does what you asked for in your question (create more and more copies of test). If you want the copies to "move on" at each call (i.e. test10 is discarded, test9 becomes test10, etc.) then you should take a look at the `logrotate` command as suggested by @Jean-Marie in the first comment.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, also understanding the syntaxis in the script, may I thank you for your answer!,
Also thanks for the others for thinking with me.
I realy love this comunity.

Comment: @Björn If this is exactly what you asked for you may mark it as the accepted answer. I added one break when i=11.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing me to this.. I have run the script several times.. i have adjusted it to my needs but something strange is happening.
After the 11th folder copy.. I getting a error message after the 10th copy, and there are folders created beyond 11.

'code'
#!/bin/bash

i=1
while true
do
    if [ -d map/test$i ]
    then
        i=$((i+1))
    else
        cp -r test map/test$i
        break
    fi
    if [ $i -eq 11 ]
    then
        rm -r map/test{1..10}
        cp -r map/test test1
    fi
'done'

Comment: That's why I added the missing `break` when the value of 11 is reached in the loop. See my corrected answer above.

Comment: ahh ok,  I see now.. it is working now. thanks!